# Does StockTwits has API which provides sentiment data

Tags: stocktwits

I had looked through https://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api

[image]

I was wondering, does StockTwits has API which provides sentiment data? As, I can't find such API in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our Sentiment API is not available for public use but you may gain access to it through our partner level api. Please email support@stocktwits.com to gain access to this.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to contact via above email. By the way, the web form to contact for partner level API seems broken - https://i.imgur.com/ABnKEmr.png

Comment: Hi @Eric , I had emailed to support@stocktwits.com but hear no reply. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng just bumped this up to priority with our guys we'll have someone get back to you asap sorry about the delay.

Comment: Hi all is this free or paid for?